# Large SSH rsync backup script is failing for only 1 dir, the rest work - (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

First, thanks for clicking on this thread and considering stuff :) We have a large script that handles backups for 30+ servers. The system that the backup server is trying to rsync with is a server that takes files from multiple other servers and stores them in sep folders with different owners. Its a jailed SCP environment.

Anyways, I got this error on one of the directories after running my script and 
can't figure out a good way to deal with it:

```
2017-03-09 02:34:06,594 - root - INFO - Command:  '/usr/bin/rsync','-akh',
                        '--rsh=ssh -c arcfour -F /root/.ssh/dbconfig','--delete',
                        '--stats','--timeout=7200','--bwlimit=2500000',
                        'shen-prod@bck3a.domain.com:~/first/incoming/ ~/second/incoming/',
                        '/usr/local/shen/backups/shen-prod/mysql/2017-03-09'
2017-03-09 02:34:06,771 - root - WARNING - Permission denied, please try again.
2017-03-09 02:34:06,772 - root - WARNING - Permission denied, please try again.
2017-03-09 02:34:06,773 - root - WARNING - Permission denied (publickey,password).
2017-03-09 02:34:06,773 - root - WARNING - rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
2017-03-09 02:34:06,774 - root - INFO - added /usr/local/domain/backups/shen-prod/mysql/2017-03-09 to the progress file
2017-03-09 02:34:06,775 - root - WARNING - rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

So what makes this kindof weird for me is that the same script is able to properly sync a different folder on the same system. Example: above it is failing on /usr/local/shen/backups/shen-prod/mysql/2017-03-09. When the next part of the script runs, it will properly sync /usr/local/corn/backups/corn-prod/mysql/2017-03-09 on the same server. Both parts of the script are referencing the same SSH key file on the same server but it won't work for shen-prod.

I cannot remove everything from the hosts files and try to start over since there are so many systems using this script constantly throughout the day. Should I just send another ssh-copy-id to the server that is tryign to get backed up? I don't want to break the other backups that are working with that key.

Let me know what you guys think on this. Im getting to the point where im over-thinking everything and kindof freezing up. Thanks in advance for your consideration!

S

EDIT: Here are the 2 parts to the actual backup script. The "corn-prod" is working properly, "shen-prod" is not working. They are both on the same host, just in separate directories. The permissions on the directories are setup properly. Each user (corn-prod and shen-prod) are owners of the directory.

```
[corn-prod]
dest_dir=/usr/local/domain/archive/backups/corn-prod
user=corn-prod
host=bck3a.domain.com
rsync_options= --rsh=ssh -c arcfour -F /root/.ssh/dbackupconfig
sources=~/primary/incoming/ ~/secondary/incoming/

[shen-prod]
dest_dir=/usr/local/domain/archive/backups/shen-prod
user=shen-prod
host=bck3a.domain.com
rsync_options= --rsh=ssh -c arcfour -F /root/.ssh/dbackupconfig
sources=~/primary/incoming/ ~/secondary/incoming/
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the rsync command to the same server that is working, and include the relevant parts of the ssh config (/root/.ssh/dbconfig I guess) for both of the rsync commands?

Comment: Just added it back in there -- thanks for the tip. Im kindof new on forums and stuff like this :)

Comment: My first guess would be that the destination is full, or not enough RAM. Try `-v, --verbose` to increase the amount of information.

Comment: You may be right! There is also an issue with HD space on the server. the backup script that was unable to run properly because of a space issue -- since that failed, it was unable to remove out the old data so it caused some issues. im going to extend the drive to make sure we have enough space and then run the backups on it again and see if it fails.  thank you for you the help!